# Freeswitch presence location on speeddial

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

I've just succesfully managed to read directory and dialplan settings over MOD_Curl_XML and fs_curl in Freeswitch.

However now there is a problem presenting itself.

I've made a speed-dial in the context default where if someone dails 201 the sipaccount 1000 is called. So far so good however the presence state is not visible on extension 201 only on extension 1000.

Is it possible to tell freeswitch that the presence state of extention 201 is the state of sip account 1000?

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

you need to tweak the `presence_id` channel variable during the call. See for more details:

1. https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/XML_User_Directory_Guide
2. http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Variable_presence_id